# Is it possible to use the DataBindTable to define values two X?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a relatively simple code that allows you to make a select to my database to extract the values ​​of two columns wanted to be both of X.
My problem using the DataBindTable method is not allowing me to define the second X.

Here is the code for the first X (the one that works):

```
protected void Chart1_Load16(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(cs1))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Consumo_Medio_Real]  FROM [dbo].[t_faturas]", con1);

        con1.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        var dt1 = new System.Data.DataTable();

        dt1.Load(rdr1);

        var enumerableTable1 = (dt1 as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();

        Chart1.DataBindTable(enumerableTable1, "Consumo_Medio_Real");
```

And this is the code for the second (doesn´t work):

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Consumo_Mes_Anterior] FROM [dbo].[t_leituras]", con);

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

    dt.Load(rdr);

    var enumerableTable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();

    Chart1.DataBindTable(enumerableTable, "Consumo_Mes_Anterior");
```

Connections:

```
     <connectionStrings>
<add name="CS1" connectionString="Data Source=ASUS;Initial Catalog=DB_SACC;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="CS" connectionString="Data Source=ASUS;Initial Catalog=DB_SACC;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: define "not work" if the second doesnt work it would suggest perhaps that your field name is wrong although it is going to a different connection... whats the error? how is it wrong or not working

Comment: The second code does not show any error, it just does not appear on the chart@BugFinder

Comment: how many records are returned in the second chunk of code?

Comment: Does not return even one! @BugFinder

Comment: then thats WHY its not working.. your SQL is not returning what you think

Comment: I tested the query it is working, but do you now other way to implement the second x? @BugFinder thanks for the help

Comment: But you just said its returning no data, so, how can it be working? nothing can graph something that doesnt exist

Comment: I don´t now i tested the select in sql and it work dosen´t return in c#

Comment: well if you get none in your code, you need to start there - you seem to have 2 connection strings, are they from different servers? are you sure you're running stuff on the right thing? only you can answer these things

Comment: why have 2 different connection strings? and god help you you're using SA.. please make an account.

Comment: now it gives the error : 
An element of the chart with the name '0' already exists in 'SeriesCollection' now it works but not both thanks @BugFinder